# select count, de dos columnas diferentes, misma tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola buenas tardes la duda que tengo es quiero hacer una consulta. de una encuesta
tengo:

Los 0 significa que dijo "No" y 1 dijo que "Si" mi tabla es :

```
pregunta 1    pregunta2   pregunta 3
1             0           1
0             1           1
```

Lo que quiero hacer es contar los 1 y los 0 para graficar.

Pero no se como agarrar y contar los unos de distintas columnas, hice algo así:

```
select COUNT(pregunta1) as p1, + COUNT(pregunta2) as p2, + COUNT(pregunta3) as p3, + COUNT(pregunta4) as p4
from rs_calificacion_ticket
where pregunta1 =1 or pregunta2=1 or pregunta3=1 or pregunta4=0
group by pregunta1, pregunta2
```

Pero no me dio resultado

trabajo en el motor ***sql managent studio v17.9***

Alguna ayuda o explíquenme los expertos que existe en esta comunidad.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres totalizar el resultado de tus preguntas en un solo campo?

Comment: si  lo que busco que me salga   personas dijeron que si=5
y en la otra columna  personas que dijeron que no =3

Answer (score 2):

Si el **Si** es 1, es factible usar la función `SUM` para obtener los votos totales de si, y restarle el total de votos de la tabla para obtener los **No**. Digamos que de la pregunta 1, con 5 personas que votaron, obtenemos que la suma es 3. Entonces basta restar 5-3 para obtener que son 2 personas que votaron no.

Ahora, en código:

```
create table prueba
(
usuario varchar(10),
pregunta1 int,
pregunta2 int,
pregunta3 int,
pregunta4 int
)

insert into prueba values ('01',1,1,1,1)
insert into prueba values ('02',1,0,0,0)
insert into prueba values ('03',1,0,0,0)
insert into prueba values ('04',1,1,1,0)
insert into prueba values ('05',0,0,1,1)
```

Ahora obtenemos el total de votos con un `COUNT` y lo almacenamos en una variable.

```
declare @w_total int
select @w_total = count(1)
from    prueba


select  sum(pregunta1) as 'Si pregunta 1',
        @w_total-sum(pregunta1) as 'No pregunta 1',
        sum(pregunta2) as 'Si pregunta 2',
        @w_total-sum(pregunta2) as 'No pregunta 2',
        sum(pregunta3) as 'Si pregunta 3',
        @w_total-sum(pregunta3) as 'No pregunta 3',
        sum(pregunta4) as 'Si pregunta 4',
        @w_total-sum(pregunta4) as 'No pregunta 4'
from prueba
```

Y esto nos devuelve el resultado deseado:

```
Si pregunta 1 No pregunta 1 Si pregunta 2 No pregunta 2 Si pregunta 3 No pregunta 3 Si pregunta 4 No pregunta 4 
------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- 
4             1             2             3             3             2             2             3
```

Comment: gracias amigo por responder soy nuevo en el foro y gracias por iluminarme soy aprendis.

Comment: Si te ha sido de utilidad la respuesta, recuerda que puedes aceptarla apretando la marca que hay bajo la puntuación de la publicación, haciéndola pasar de gris a verde.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) cant_encuestados
,count(iif(pregunta1=1,1,NULL)) p1_si
,count(iif(pregunta1=0,1,NULL)) p1_no       
,count(iif(pregunta2=1,1,NULL)) p2_si       
,count(iif(pregunta2=0,1,NULL)) p2_no       
,count(iif(pregunta3=1,1,NULL)) p3_si      
,count(iif(pregunta3=0,1,NULL)) p3_no       
,count(iif(pregunta4=1,1,NULL)) p4_si       
,count(iif(pregunta5=0,1,NULL)) p4_no        
from rs_calificacion_ticket
```